# Include the chosen tags in the search criteria for "Questions that may already have your answer."

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, asking-questions, tag-search

In order to improve the question asking page, it would be prevalent to include the tags in the search results.

Many users seem to type their question as their title. However, even with a clear title and a very limiting tag, the search results for the "Questions that may already have your answer" do not seem to come very close to being successful.

This more than likely leads to both tags being overly present in titles, and also duplicate questions being posted as the system has failed to identify existing content.

As a result, the system must be improved in order to remedy the situation.

Here is a real world example: a user is unsure how to sort an array in JavaScript.

[image]

<sub>*yes, that is a hand drawn red circle angry face (re: swift, codeigniter, localization, Ruby, NSDate)*</sub>

Swift is Objective-C for those not familiar, which is to say it is most certainly not related to JavaScript whatsoever. In fact, **none of those results are relevant**. The odd thing is that the search feature at Stack Overflow already provides for using tags as criteria.

Were the feature to automatically include the tag in the search, you would have gotten these results (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+sort+an+array+%5Bjavascript%5D) as number 1 and number 2

+148 [How to sort an array of objects with jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript)

and

+219 [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

These two scenarios, one of no results and off topic languages with regards to JavaScript, versus the *actual correct answer* show a disconnect often alluded to by users: that question askers don't do their research. While a question asker is expected to search elsewhere, many new users are not aware of all of the features of the site and go straight to asking. Allowing them to find their answer while asking would prevent many duplicate questions, and perhaps many low quality questions as well since content which is already on the site has had time to be curated and polished.

While this one example may seem localized to Stack Overflow, it is just a good example. This scenario would apply Exchange wide as every exchange strives to prevent duplicate and low quality content.

tl;dr; **Include the chosen tags in the search criteria for "Questions that may already have your answer."**